# Unable to build c++ application using nw-gyp build. Error: error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515

Tags: node-webkit

I have tried to set up nw-gyp on Windows 8.1 x64 by following the following link:

[nw-gyp installation guide](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-gyp)

For this I installed:

- Python v2.7
- Node v4.2.2 (Setted its path too in environment variable)
- npm v2.14.7
- node-webkit v0.12.3
- Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012 for Windows Desktop [Express version From Here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9816758)

after this I installed nw-gyp using the following command.

- npm install -g nw-gyp

Now I tried to run the demo app provided here [nw-gyp Example](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/tree/master/test/addons/hello-world)

Now I configure the app using command:

- nw-gyp configure --target=0.12.3

0.12.3 is my node webkit version. The configuration is successful and I am able to get the build folder. But further when I try to build the addon using command

- nw-gyp build

I get the following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.targets(146,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515. [E:\PacificCX\testSecond\build\binding.vcxproj]
```

Here is the full log:

```
E:\PacificCX\testSecond>nw-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using nw-gyp@0.12.4
gyp info using node@4.2.2 | win32 | x64
(node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio
instead.
gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(29
7,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.
  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version nu
mber. [E:\PacificCX\testSecond\build\binding.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x
64.targets(146,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515. [E:\Pa
cificCX\testSecond\build\binding.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\kamaldeep.singh\AppData\Roam
ing\npm\node_modules\nw-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kamaldeep.sin
gh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\nw-gyp\\bin\\nw-gyp.js" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\PacificCX\testSecond
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2
gyp ERR! nw-gyp -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! not ok
```

[image]

Someone please help me solve this out. Thanks in advance.

Here is the link to my complete sample program. [Download Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz1uVMPq87g1Z05iYXFsZW1Oc2c/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

solved this problem by updating Visual Studio 2012.